# how to improve speed of File transfer operation

Tags: windows-7, performance, 64-bit, file-transfer, teracopy

I'm using windows 7 64 bits with the following performances:

```
CPU     Specification   : Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4200U CPU @ 1.60GHz
        L1 Data cache   2 x 32 KBytes, 8-way set associative, 64-byte line size
        L1 Instruction cache    2 x 32 KBytes, 8-way set associative, 64-byte line size
        L2 cache    2 x 256 KBytes, 8-way set associative, 64-byte line size
        L3 cache    3 MBytes, 12-way set associative, 64-byte line size

Core Speed  798.4 MHz
Turbo Mode  supported, enabled

Memory Type DDR3
Memory Size 8 GBytes
Channels    Dual

Memory Frequency    798.4 MHz (1:6)

Windows Version Microsoft Windows 7 (6.1) Ultimate Edition 64-bit Service Pack 1 (Build 7601)
```

---

```
Hard drive :
Connector SATA
File system : NTFS
Model : TOSHIBA MQ01ABF050 SCSI Disk Device
Bytes/Sector : 512
Partitions : 5 
Size : 465,76 GB (500 105 249 280 bytes)
Total Cylinders : 60 801
Total Sectors : 976 768 065
Tracks/Cylinder : 255
```

The copy operation is very slow in my computer,it's true that there is only 12Gb free on my C drive (from 200Gb) and i haven't run a format since installation date 06/06/2014. I'm trying to solve any problem witout the need of formating windows but with this problem i could not found a solution.

I have also used **TeraCopy pro 3.0** but i haven't noticed any improvements in copying speed, i have cleaned my laptop from viruses using malwarebyte and avast , cleaner also for registry adw cleaner, i made defragmentation some times but no results....

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: You haven't really provided enough information to answer your question.  Copying files is not much related to the speed of your processor or amount of RAM in the computer.  Instead, provide details about  your storage devices and how they are connected to your computer (SATA, USB, Ethernet, WiFi)

Comment: @WesLarson my hard drive use SATA and it use NTFS file system => i have updated the info tell me plz if i need to provide more info

Comment: Please define "very slow".  If copying suddenly got faster (or slower), how could you tell?  Have you done any testing to see just how fast or slow your hard drive is running?  There are some free third-party benchmarking tools you might want to look into (just google 'HDD speed test').  You might also want to see how your hard drive model ranks against other hard drives--I found this indicating that yours is relatively mediocre ( http://hdd.userbenchmark.com/SpeedTest/2789/TOSHIBA-MQ01ABF050 ).  So it looks like it's just a slow HDD.  Upgrading to a fast SSD is probably your best option.

Comment: @WesLarson maybe you're right i have a slow laptop http://www.userbenchmark.com/UserRun/856547 btw i was very disapointed from the benchmarks :p